# Lumenera camera with OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I have a Lumenera mono camera, along with its own SDK. Im trying to fetch single frames using the camera APIs and then feed them into OpenCV imgshow. The issue I have is I dont understand the camera's own image format which should be "raw 8bit images" according with their manual. The image displayed by OpenCV has blurred/doubled lines or it is repeated many times. Anyone knows how to convert these raw frames to Mat?

Thanks!

Here below is my actual TakeScreenshow fn:

```
    public Mat TakeRawSnapshot()
    {
        Mat Result;

        try
        {
            if (!api.IsCameraValid(m_CameraHandle))
                throw new Exception("Camera not valid!");

            var frameFormat = api.GetFormat(m_CameraHandle);
            var colorFormat = api.GetProperty(m_CameraHandle, dll.LucamProperty.COLOR_FORMAT);

            int rawFrameSize = (frameFormat.Width * frameFormat.Height) / (frameFormat.SubSampleY * frameFormat.SubSampleX);
            if (frameFormat.PixelFormat == dll.LucamPixelFormat.PF_16)
                rawFrameSize *= api.GetPixelFormatBytesPerPixel(m_CameraHandle);


            IntPtr rawFrame = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawFrameSize);
            //IntPtr rgbFrame = rgbFrame = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawFrameSize * 3);

            if (!dll.LucamTakeSnapshot(m_CameraHandle, ref currentSnapshotParameters, rawFrame))
            {
                var Err = dll.LucamGetLastError();
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not take a picture because of {0}", Err));
            }

            dll.LucamImageFormat imf = api.GetImageFormat(m_CameraHandle);

            dll.LucamConversion frameConversion = new dll.LucamConversion(dll.LucamDemosaicMethod.HIGH_QUALITY, dll.LucamCorrectionMatrix.NONE);

            /*if (colorFormat != (float)dll.LucamColorFormat.MONO)
            {
                
                if (imf.PixelFormat == dll.LucamPixelFormat.PF_8)
                {
                    dll.LucamConvertFrameToRgb24(m_CameraHandle, rgbFrame, rawFrame, imf.Width / frameFormat.SubSampleX, imf.Height / frameFormat.SubSampleY, imf.PixelFormat, ref frameConversion);
                    imf.PixelFormat = dll.LucamPixelFormat.PF_24;
                }

                if (imf.PixelFormat == dll.LucamPixelFormat.PF_16)
                {
                    dll.LucamConvertFrameToRgb48(m_CameraHandle, rgbFrame, rawFrame, imf.Width / frameFormat.SubSampleX, imf.Height / frameFormat.SubSampleY, imf.PixelFormat, ref frameConversion);
                    imf.PixelFormat = dll.LucamPixelFormat.PF_48;
                }
            }
            else*/
            {
                imf.PixelFormat = dll.LucamPixelFormat.PF_8;
                if (!dll.LucamConvertFrameToGreyscale8(m_CameraHandle, rawFrame, rawFrame, imf.Width / frameFormat.SubSampleX, imf.Height / frameFormat.SubSampleY, imf.PixelFormat, ref frameConversion))
                {
                    var Err = dll.LucamGetLastError();
                    throw new Exception($"{Err}");
                }
            }

            Result = new Mat(imf.Width / frameFormat.SubSampleX, imf.Height / frameFormat.SubSampleY, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 1, rawFrame, 0);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
            throw ex;
        }

       
        return Result;
    }
```

If i call camera's own LumeneraSaveImage fn then the image is correctly saved to disk, so TakeRawSnapshot is working fine, they're doing some conversion in their LumeneraSaveImage.

Comment: Try allocating a new image as a destination when converting. Using the same pointer as both input and output may case issues. I would also try creating a regular .net bitmap and saving it. That way you can isolate potential OpenCV issues.

Comment: thank you @JonasH for the comment.. By better digging into their tiny c# examples, they indeed do this: raw byte array -> bitmap (Format8bppIndexed, Marshal Copy to unmanaged ptr) -> display into winforms. Having a bitmap then I can convert it to Mat. Will try and let you know!

Comment: show the problem please. show pictures.